# Suppose $P_0$ and $P$ are projections. Do they commute when...

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I saw this claim in a book which I think is incorrect:

Given a vector space $X$ and a subspace $E$, suppose $P_0$ and $P$ be projections such that $P_0x = x$ iff $x \in E$ and $Px=x$ if $x \in E$. Then $P_0P = PP_0 = P_0$.

My counter example: suppose $X$ is $R^2$ and $E$ be the subspace generated by $ \left( \begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 1 \end{array} \right)$. Let $P_0$ be $ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$ and $P$ be $ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \end{array} \right)$. Clearly the hypothesis is satisfied, however $P_0P = P$ whereas $PP_0 = P_0$.

Is the claim correct if $P$ is required to be orthogonal?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but is the claim correct if $P$ is required to be orthogonal?

Comment: It's always true that $P_0 P = P$ and $P P_0 = P_0$.  This is because $P_0$ and $P$ fix all vectors in $\text{Ran}(P) = \text{Ran}(P_0)$.

Comment: Why would $Ran(P) = Ran(P_0)$? It might well be the case that $P_0$ is the projection of $R^3$ onto the $z$-axis and $P$ the projection of $R^3$ onto the $y$-$z$ plane.

Comment: Because it's explicitly stated: $P_0 x = x $ iff $x \in E$ and $P x = x$ iff $x \in E$.  The range of a projection is the set of vectors fixed by that projection.

Comment: No, please read the question carefully again. It's iff for $P_0$ but if for $P$.

Comment: Ah, then $E = \text{Ran}(P_0) \subseteq \text{Ran}(P)$.  So you do have $P P_0 = P_0$., but you don't know about $P_0 P$.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I know the answer now and just put it here in case someone wants to use it in the future. (Lame excuse: I haven't gone through that part).

If $P$ and $P_0$ are orthogonal and bounded, they are self-adjoint, i.e. $P_0 = P_0^*$, $P = P^*$ hence $P_0 = (PP_0)^* = P_0^*P^* = P_0P$.

Answer (score 0):

With X a vector space, let $E = $ Range $(P_0)$ and $F = $ Range $(P)$

As in comments the condition "$P_0x = x$ iff $x \in E$ and $Px=x$ if $x \in E$." $\implies E \subset F$.
If we assume an inner product space then  $ E \subset F \implies F^\perp \subset E^\perp $ and $  E^\perp , F^\perp $ are topologically closed subspaces (even if the space is not complete, i.e. Hilbert).

Then we can take the orthogonal complement of $  F^\perp $ in $ E^\perp $, call it $G$

If $X$ is a Hilbert space then by the "projection theorem"  $X = E \oplus E^\perp = E \oplus F^\perp \oplus G$ and any $x \in X$ is represented uniquely as $e + f` + g$ with $e,  f`, g$ in $E, F^\perp, G$ respectively.

Then $P_0(x) = e$; $P(x) = e + f`$;  $P(P_0(x)) = e$; $P_0(P(x)) = e$ and the result holds if these are orthogonal  projections in a Hilbert space.

But this is not the end of the story - see the paper by Rehder - When do Projections Commute 
https://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/j/zna.1980.35.issue-4/zna-1980-0415/zna-1980-0415.pdf